# Questions about css not being applied

Tags: css

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm building a web page. The style of the web page uses bootstrap. In the following is some css. However, as shown in the picture above, the middle line is not applied. Can you tell me why?

Comment: A strikethrough means the current rule has been overrided by another.

Comment: probably you set an another style to this class that override this bootstrap declaretion

Answer (score 3):

The strikethrough basically means that the style you are trying to apply is overridden by another style that applies these styles to the same element.

This could be because you called bootstrap which overrides your style declaration. This could be overcome by *linking your .css file after linking bootstrap CSS*  or you could use the `!important` keyword after each style which will force your style.

```
.card-danger{
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
    border-color: #d9534f !important;
}
```

If this doesn't work, then link the style file after the bootstrap css.

I don't know more about this because I don't know the structure of the element you have used to style. It is more advisable to not use '!important' as it is bad engineering and later on the project, you will get the same kind of errors but it will get the job done I hope.